# changing print output line

Tags: r, printing

I'm wondering if is there a possibility to have dynamic print output.
Instead of having something like this simple countdown

```
for (i in 5:1){
  cat(paste(i, "\n"))
}
5 
4 
3 
2 
1 
>
```

I would love to have code that reprint current output (e.g. 5) with next value (4) etc. Is that possible in R?

Comment: can you give the expected output? what do you mean 5 with 4? is it like 5_4? also give a logic , for example if 5 with 4 comes then why should not it come with 3 etc

Comment: @Learner see my answer, I have already found needed code. Anyway, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it. The code is

```
for (i in 5:1) {cat("\r",i)}
```

Being a little bit slower:

```
for (i in 5:1) {Sys.sleep(0.5); cat("\r",i)}
```